# Notepad++ mass multiply a specific integer after a text

Tags: python, notepad++

I have notepad++ with python script installed, is there a way to mass multiply all numbers that come after a specific string?

For example:
`ExperienceGained 10 + X`

I have thousands of those lines and I need to multiply all X by 3.

I tried this but without any success:

```
def multiply_number_in_context(match):
    return "{0}{1}{2}{3}".format(match.group(1), str(int(match.group(3))*3), '"')

editor.rereplace(r'(ExperienceGained 10 + )(\d+)"', multiply_number_in_context)
```

Comment: Why do you use 4 formatting fields and pass only 3 values to `.format()`?

Comment: sorry i just found this code on another thread but it was vague so i tried to modify it.

Comment: ```def multiply_number_in_context(match):
    return "{0}".format(int(match.group(1))*3)

editor.rereplace(r'(\ExperienceGained 10 + (\d+)', multiply_number_in_context)```

is this better ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

- Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
- Copy this code and save the file (for example multiply.py):

```py
import re

def multiply(match):
    val = int(match.group(1)) * 3
    return str(val)
    
editor.rereplace(r'^ExperienceGained 10 \+ \K(\d+)$', multiply)
```

- Open the file you want to modify
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> multiply)
- Done

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]